# Selecting table to use in FROM clause based on certain condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

I have the following schema :

```
Purchase             : pur_dt | pur_amt | item_code | quantity 
ItemListForSoftware  : item_code | item_desc | ...
ItemListForHardware  : item_code | item_desc | ...
```

Now, I need to fetch item_desc from either of the Item tables based on the item_code of Purchase.

If item_code starts with S then it should look up in ItemListForSoftware
else from ItemListForHardware

Something like this

```
if(item_code starts with S){
 select pur_dt,pur_amt,item_desc,quantity from Purchase, ItemListForSoftware where Purchase.item_code=ItemListForSoftware.item_code
}else{
  select pur_dt,pur_amt,item_desc,quantity from Purchase, ItemListForHardware where Purchase.item_code=ItemListForHardware.item_code
}
```

Is there a way to do this via single SQL Query?

Comment: Probably two left. joins. Coalesce results to combine the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select p.pur_dt, p.pur_amt,
       coalesce(ifs.item_desc, ifh.item_desc) as item_desc,
       p.quantity
from Purchase p left join
     ItemListForSoftware ifs
     on p.item_code = ifs.item_code and
        p.item_code like 'S%' left join
     ItemListForHardware ifh
     on p.item_code = ifh.item_code and
        p.item_code not like 'S%';
```

Note the correct `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Will please let me know what is coalesce() doing?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem by `LEFT JOIN`ing to both tables and using the `item_code` to select the appropriate data:

```
SELECT p.pur_dt, p.pur_amt, 
       CASE WHEN LEFT(p.item_code, 1) = 'S' THEN s.item_desc
            ELSE h.item_desc
       END AS item_desc
       p.quantity
FROM Purchase p
LEFT JOIN ItemListForSoftware s ON p.item_code=s.item_code
LEFT JOIN ItemListForHardware h ON p.item_code=h.item_code
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is just as simple as you wrote:

```
select
  pur_dt,
  pur_amt,
  case
    when left(item_cide, 1) = 'S' then
      (select item_desc from ItemListForSoftware as d where d.item_code = p.item_code)
    else
      (select item_desc from ItemListForHardware as d where d.item_code = p.item_code)
  end as item_desc,
  quantity
from Purchase as p;
```

Surely it will to work only if there is only 0 or 1 row in `ItemListForSoftware` and `ItemListForHardware` tables per item.

PS: Note that it could be faster a bit then joining three tables.